# Multiple foreign key for a table with a table type column

Tags: sql, database, foreign-key-relationship

Let's say I have this database tables:

**Cash**

- ID (PK)
- Amount

**Cheque**

- ID (PK)
- Amount
- Number

**Card**

- ID (PK)
- Amount
- Type

**Transaction**

- ID (PK)
- Type CHECK (Type => 1 AND Type <= 2)
- TypeID

**Transaction.Type** would store what type of transaction, whether its Cash (1), Cheque (2) or Card (3).  **Transaction.TypeID** would store the primary key of the transaction type; if the **Transaction.Type** is 1 it would store **Cash.ID**, 2 if it would store **Cheque.ID**, 3 if it would store **Card.ID**.

How should I define a foreign key constraint for **Transaction.TypeID** to make sure referential integrity with the **Cash**, **Cheque** and **Card** tables?

I could create a computed column for the 3 parent tables like so:

**Cash**

- ID (PK)
- Amount
- TransactionType CHECK (Type = 1)

**Cheque**

- ID (PK)
- Amount
- Number
- TransactionType CHECK (Type = 2)

**Card**

- ID (PK)
- Amount
- TransactionType CHECK (Type = 3)

and then create a foreign key using the **ID** and the **TransactionType** of the parent tables.  Is there another way to do this without adding a new table or dramatically changing the schema of the tables?

Comment: The tables you mention does not seem to be related with the columns you show here. What is the relation between the tables?

Comment: @lalborno: Transaction.TypeID would relate to either the Cash.ID, Cheque.ID or Card.ID depending on the value of Transaction.Type

Comment: I think your solution is ok. Doesn't seem to be another that simple.